# Using kislyuk/yq returns syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER with additional /0 at the end

Tags: jq, yq

I am using kislyuk/yq - The more often talked about version, which is a wrapper over jq, written in Python using the PyYAML library for YAML parsing

The version is yq 2.12.2

My jq is jq-1.6

I'm using ubuntu and bash scripts to do my parsing.

I wrote this as bash

```
alias=alias1
token=abc

yq -y -i  ".tokens += { $alias: { value: $token }}" /root/.github.yml
```

I get the following error

```
jq: error: abc/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
.tokens += { alias1: { value: abc }}
```

I don't get it. Why would there be a /0 at the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `abc` is not interpreted as a *literal* string, when the double quotes are expanded by the shell. The underlying `jq` wrapper tries to match with `abc` as a standard built-in or a user-defined function which it was not able to resolve to, hence the error.

A JSON string (needed for `jq`) type needs to be quoted with `".."` to be consistent with the JSON grammar. One way would be to pass the arg via command line with the `--arg` support

```sh
yq -y -i --arg t "$token" --arg a "$alias" '.tokens += { ($a): { value: $t } }' /root/.github.yml
```

Or have a quoting mess like below, which I don't recommend at all

```sh
yq -y -i '.tokens += { "'"$alias"'": { value: "'"$token"'" }}' /root/.github.yml
```